# Python join elements with same index

Tags: python

I have a file with few thousand lines. I'd like to populate the dictionary line by line. The gene can work as a key. If the gene is found, it would append only the "rest" as values. I'd like to join the values for example with comma. This is where I'm now.

```
listfile = {}

with open("Desktop/testfile", "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
        lines=lines.strip()
        gene=lines.split()[0]
        rest = lines.split()[1:]


        if gene not in listfile:
            listfile[gene] = rest
            #print gene, rest
        else:
            for items in rest:

                listfile[gene].append(items)    


for items in listfile.items():
    print items
```

input:

```
ACCA    39072094753 D   12
ACCA    983954875454    G   11
ACCA    098540980985    F   22
```

output:

```
('ACCA', ['39072094753', 'D', '12', '983954875454', 'G', '11', '098540980985', 'F', '22'])
```

expected output:

```
('ACCA', ['39072094753','983954875454','098540980985' 'D','G','F', '12','11','22'])
```

Comment: Can you make your question clear by providing your input?

Comment: The difference between the output and the needed output appears to be just the order of the entries and the space after the commas. Am I missing something?

Also, you can use `listfile[gene].extend(rest)` and avoid `for items in rest:`

Comment: Do you want the values to be a list or a long string containing comma separated elements?

Comment: Either way is probably ok. Long string with different separator than within the values would allow further processing if needed.

Comment: what's the rationale for the output format? it might be hard to parse as it has potentially unbounded sublists with no delimiters between columns. Probably safer would be `('ACCA', ['39072094753','983954875454','098540980985'], ['D','G','F'], ['12','11','22'])`.

Comment: I assume I don't need further processing so was a bit lazy, but you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general solution that works with any number of columns in the input file:

```
import collections
import itertools

genes_info = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("testfile") as genes_file:
    for line in genes_file:
        fields = line.split()
        genes_info[fields[0]].append(fields[1:])  # Stores each row information

# Conversion of the row-first gene information into column-first information:
for gene_info in genes_info.itervalues():
    gene_info[:] = itertools.chain(*zip(*gene_info))

print genes_info
```

gives

```
{'ACCA': ['39072094753', '983954875454', '098540980985', 'D', 'G', 'F', '12', '11', '22']}
```

(If you need a dictionary instead of a mostly equivalent defaultdict you can add at the end `genes_info = dict(genes_info)`.)

If you want to keep column values together, use instead the simpler `gene_info[:] = zip(*gene_info)`. This gives:

```
{'ACCA': [('39072094753', '983954875454', '098540980985'), ('D', 'G', 'F'), ('12', '11', '22')]}
```

In fact, `zip()` essentially transforms rows into columns.

**PS**: `line.split()` automatically removes empty strings, so the final newline is in effect automatically removed: I simplified my original `line.strip().split()`, where `strip()` was therefore unnecessary.

Comment: How would you do to achieve this as miraculixx suggested if I need further processing: ('ACCA', ['39072094753','983954875454','098540980985'], ['D','G','F'], ['12','11','22'])

Comment: Then it's even simpler: you remove `itertools.chain(*…)` and keep only `… = zip(…)`. You can see `zip()` as converting rows into columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, you have same amount of space separated values in each line. if not, the longest of them will be used for zip.

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import itertools
listfile = {}

with open("Desktop/testfile", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split()
        gene = line[0]
        rest = line[1:]

        if gene not in listfile:
            listfile[gene] = []
        listfile[gene].append(rest)

for i in listfile:
    x = i.get()
    print(i, list(itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(*x))))
```

Comment: This is the essentially the same as my solution, right? I don't think that we need to multiply similar solutions. :)

Comment: Ah.. I guess we both started at the same time, with no answers here.

Comment: Yeah, that's why StackOverflow displays a message when new answers are available (this would have showed you mine). :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it.

```
openedFile = open('data.txt', 'r')

largeNumber = []
letter = []
smallNumber = []

for line in openedFile:
    splittedContent = line.split()
    largeNumber.append(splittedContent[1])
    letter.append(splittedContent[2])
    smallNumber.append(splittedContent[3])

print ('ACCA', largeNumber + letter + smallNumber)
```

Output:

```
('ACCA', ['39072094753', '983954875454', '098540980985', 'D', 'G', 'F', '12', '11', '22'])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just need the comma seperated string for the output, you can just do:

```
print ",".join(listfile.items())
```

I think for further processing it would be usefull to keep the attributes in a list.

Comment: You get a `TypeError`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a good usecase for a `defaultdict`

```
from from collections import defaultdict
listfile = defaultdict(lambda : [])

with open("Desktop/testfile", "r") as f:
    all_lines = (l.split for l in f)
    for line in all_lines:
        first = line[0]
        rest = line[1:]
        listfile[first].extend(rest)
```

Comment: This does not put the values together as needed: they need to be grouped by columns instead of by line.